# Inline IF statement to change icon class based on flask variable

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I would like to know if this is even possible to do with inline if function. I guess the alternative is to do it using JS. I've found some posts on here asking almost similar to what I want to do, but the resolutions is not what I exactly expected or was done in PHP.

```
<i class="fa fa-server {{ 'danger' if {{ system_health }} == 'Not Good' else 'primary' }} font-large-2 float-left"></i>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `system_health` is text variable you can use following template:

```
<i class="fa fa-server {% if system_health == 'Not Good' %}danger{% else %}primary{% endif %} font-large-2 float-left"></i>
```

Note that I put variable name without `{{` and `}}` when dealing with I use it inside if statement.

```
import jinja2
t = jinja2.Template('''<i class="fa fa-server {% if system_health == 'Not Good' %}danger{% else %}primary{% endif %} font-large-2 float-left"></i>''')
print(t.render(system_health = 'Not Good'))
print(t.render(system_health = 'OK'))
```

output:

```
<i class="fa fa-server danger font-large-2 float-left"></i>
<i class="fa fa-server primary font-large-2 float-left"></i>
```

*(tested in python version 3.7.3 and jinja2 version 2.11.1)*

Comment: Thanks that worked and saved me from a massive headache! Only reason why I tried it my inital way is because in some other code I was doing the below and it works, so not sure why it wouldn't work in this case.

 <option value="True" {{ "selected='selected'" if load_rows == 'True' else "" }}>True</option>